# Java- Best approach for sending millions records over the network using http protocol

Tags: java, rest, http, scalability, http2

I need to transfer almost a million records over the wire using http protocol, currently I am using apache  http pool rest client n sending one by one. 
Are they any better way and faster way to achieve this? Any framework or any other way in java?
Is there any way I can implement multi writer concepts in java.

Edit Note: Server does not support file upload or batch requests. However they are open to discuss some other way like streaming or http2 protocol but I am not sure how to progress on these.

Comment: Try sending them in batches.

Comment: Or why not make a file, compress it, and send it in one upload?

Comment: Unfortunately server does not support batch or file uploads, so I can’t use above mentioned solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If the server can handle big requests I would send them all in one request. I have tested such scenarios in the past with a Java HTTP client and a Java HTTP server, where I sent requests of up to 500MB in size with no problems.